# sqlalchemy and postgres: insert from select where exists

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use sqlalchemy to create a query (for postgres) which looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c)
SELECT a, b, c FROM (
  VALUES
  (1, 2, 3),
  (4, 5, 6),
) AS x (a, b, c)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table2 t
  WHERE t.id = x.a
)
```

I can happily generate the VALUES clause in the middle as:

```
sel = select(Values(column(a, BigInteger), column(b, BigInteger), column(c, BigInteger), name='x').data([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]))
```

And I can make the EXISTS clause as:

```
ex = session.query(Table2).filter(Table2.id == sel.c.a)
```

But when I print out the resultant SQL from the combination of the two statements, the entire SELECT clause is repeated, with the values:

```
>>> str(sel)
'SELECT x.a, x.b, x.c FROM (VALUES (:param_1, :param_2, :param_3), (:param_4, :param_5, :param_6)) AS x (a, b, c)'

>>> str(ex)
'EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2, (SELECT x.a AS a, x.b AS b, x.c AS c FROM (VALUES (:param_1, :param_2, :param_3), (:param_4, :param_5, :param_6)) AS x (a, b, c)) AS x WHERE table2.id = x.a)'

>>> str(sel.where(ex))
'SELECT x.a, x.b, x.c FROM (VALUES (:param_1, :param_2, :param_3), (:param_4, :param_5, :param_6)) AS x (a, b, c) WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2, (SELECT x.a AS a, x.b AS b, x.c AS c FROM (VALUES (:param_7, :param_8, :param_9), (:param_10, :param_11, :param_12)) AS x (a, b, c)) AS x \nWHERE table2.id = x.a)'
```

Can anyone shed some light on how I can achieve what I'm trying to do? Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: You are using a tool (software with a pre-determined algorithm) to create your query. You should not care what that query is provided it meets 2 requirements. 1- It produces the correct answer and 2- it satisfies your service level agreement (i.e. it is fast enough).  If it fails either of those perhaps you are asking the wrong question. If you want to control the structure of the query then write it do not generate it.